# VUE and Axios API : Passing error code from api, to store, to vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

This very well, might be marked as a duplicate, and if it is i'm sorry. Been googling around *a lot* to find how to actually do this, without any proper solution (i'm not a vue expert though..)

Basically.. what i'm trying to do.. Is passing success or failure from the api => store => vue component. If error... i will present the user with the error code (for now...)

**The way of things..**

1) Method triggered from vue component. Dispatch to $store (modal.vue)

2) State action is triggered to set mutationtype and calling API.

3) Api method is called.

4) Returning both success or error, AND http.statuscode....

**MODAL.VUE**

```
doRefund: function(){
            this.$store.dispatch('doRefund', {
                    Username : this.loggedInUser.account.username,
                    OrderID: this.selectedOrder.orderid,
                    IsFeeApplied: false,
                    CreditAmount: this.refundAmount,
                    ChargeFee: 0.0,
                    Reason: "reason-not-specified",
                    Description: this.comment,
                    BearerToken: "Bearer " + this.accessToken
            })
            .then(result => {
                if(result === true){
                  alertify.success('It worked!')
                }
                else{
                    alertify.alert('There was an error, and the errorcode is' + errorcode ????)
                }
            })
        }
```

**STORE.JS**

```
doRefund({ commit }, refundParams){
        api.tryRefund(refundParams)
        .then(refundCompleted => {
            commit(types.SET_REFUND_COMPLETED, true)
            return true;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            //TODO: How to i fetch, and pass the errorcode ? 
            commit(types.SET_REFUND_COMPLETED, false)
            return false;

        })
    },
```

**API.JS**

```
tryRefund(refundParams) {
    console.log('=== try ====');
    console.log( refundParams );
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': ' application/json',
                'Authorization': refundParams.BearerToken
            }
        };
        return axios.post('the-url-to-the-service', refundParams, config)
            .then(
                () => resolve(true))
            .catch( error => {
                console.log('=== ERROR ====');
                console.log( error.response );

            })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the `error.response` to the `reject` handler in your `tryRefund` method in your `api.js` file:

```
.catch(error => {
  console.log('=== ERROR ====');
  console.log( error.response );
  reject(error)
})
```

Then, you should throw the error in the `doRefund` action method:

```
.catch(err => {
  //TODO: How to i fetch, and pass the errorcode ? 
  commit(types.SET_REFUND_COMPLETED, false)
  throw err;
})
```

And then catch it in the `catch` handler for the `$dispatch` method:

```
this.$store.dispatch('doRefund', {
  ...               
})
.then(result => {
  ...
})
.catch(error => { 
  console.log(error); // this is the error you want
})
```

Comment: Thanks @thanksd :) That was _exactly_ what i was after :)

Comment: Easy and awsome description on how to do it... wish that every question i had asked, was answered like this.

Comment: Only weird thing.. is that it seems that the $dispatch is fired twice ? Know why ?

Comment: That means for some reason the `doRefund` method of the modal component is being called multiple times. Not enough context in your post and definitely unrelated, so I'd post a new question with related code if you can't figure it out

Comment: @thanksd if he eliminates the `.catch` in the store (say for instance, he doesn't need to commit `SET_REFUND_COMPLETED` then reject throws it to the final catch in this modal automatically? just curious since it would seem the only way to solve this is to have a reject-throw-reject pattern